# Unable to open and read every file in folder in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am currently having an issue where I can't output the content in the second file, instead it outputs the contents of the first file twice. How can I create a loop that outputs the content of every file in this directory?

**My Code**

```
import discord
import discord.ext import commands
import os, glob
import uuid
@bot.command()
async def listjobs(ctx):

    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Jobs', description='Placeholder text that explains how to use this bot')

    alljobs = os.listdir(cwd+'/jobs')
    mylines = []

    for job in alljobs:
        embed.add_field(name='Job ID', value=job.split('.')[0])
        with open(cwd+'/jobs/'+job, 'r+') as f:
            #print(f.readlines())
            for line in f:
                mylines.append(line)
            distance = mylines[1]
            claimedby = mylines[2]
            embed.add_field(name='Distance', value=distance.split(':')[1])
            embed.add_field(name='Claimed by', value=claimedby.split(':')[1])
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHpx4.png)
*I am aware that I am not displaying the first line (legs:....) at the moment*

**Text file #1**

```
Leg: ksfo to koat
Distance: 1000 miles
Claimed by: no one
```

**Text File #2**

```
Leg: klax to kphx
Distance: 550 miles
Claimed by: no one
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking the data from the list "mylines", but you never clean "mylines".
You are appending the lines from each file on list but never removing them

So, the lines

`distance = mylines[1] claimedby = mylines[2]`

always refer to lines 1 and 2 of the first file.

To solve this you should put the initialization of "mylines" inside the loop so on each pass of the loop it will remove the previous lines from the list.